# JPA PreUpdate called when using Entity id in Join Operation

Tags: java, spring, jpa, repository, entitylisteners

I have a spring application and use JPA with a sql db. In my application the data model is very complex, but I will use this example as it shows everything I need: Parent 1:n Child 1:n Grandchildren.

**My Goal**: Everytime a child or grandchild gets an update, give me a list of all linked parents. To achieve this, I want to load the parent from the database instead of navigating with getters, for performance reasons.

**What I already did:** I have an `EntityListener` with a `preUpdate` method. Within this method I call the repository with: `parentRepository.findParentsByChild_Id()`/`findParentsByGrandchild_Id()` (Both with their respective queries)

**What happens**: Let's say I update a child, so `preUpdate` with the child entity is called. Now I execute `findParentsByChild_Id()` and by doing this, `preUpdate` with the same child entity is called again. So I end up in an endless loop. Same case with updating a grandchild.

At first, I thought the entity has to be saved first so I tried post-update, with the same result.

Now I just can't understand why pre/post-update is called when I use the updated entity id in a findBy operation in a repository of a different entity.